# Spring MVC: Get Unnamed Request Parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the simplest way to access an unnamed request parameter in a Spring MVC controller? Is there an annotation for this similar to `@RequestParam`?

HTTP Delete request with unnamed parameter:

```
http://localhost/myEndPoint?someUnnamedParam
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/myEndPoint"}, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteThing() {
        // Do something with unnamed param
    }
}
```

***Details:** Spring 3.0.7*

Comment: What do mean by "unnamed" parameter?

Comment: @GriffeyDog it is of the form `?value` as opposed to `?name=value`

Comment: How about doing /myEndPoint/value and using @PathVariable?

Comment: @GriffeyDog I am working from a predefined API and must consume it in the form `http://localhost/myEndPoint?someUnnamedParam`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand.

In `/myEndPoint?someUnnamedParam`, you have a parameter named `someUnnamedParam` with a `String` value of `""`, ie. an empty `String`. It's parsed as an equivalent to `/myEndPoint?someUnnamedParam=`.

You can get a set of parameter names and use those as values.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/myEndPoint"}, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteThing((@RequestParam Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    Set<String> paramNames = params.keySet();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/myEndPoint"}, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteThing(HttpServletRequest request) {        
    String param = request.getQueryString();
        // Do something with request
}
```

and perform any operations you need on `request`

Comment: Is there a non Java-EE alternative to `HttpServletRequest`? Also what method would I call on that to get the unnamed parameter?

Comment: @MikeRylander I see you already found the answer to your question :)

Comment: Must be the accepted one because it answer the question without asking "why don't you do this in another way?"